# Solving diff. equations involving vector product

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics

[image]

I've managed to do part (a) by dotting the original equation by $\underline{\dot r}$ however I'm having troubles with part (b):

We've learnt very few things to deal with these types of equations these are:

Cross it with something
Dot it with something
then note for some identities such as $\dfrac{d(\underline{r} \times \frac{d\underline{r}}{dt})}{dt} = \underline{r}\times \underline{ \ddot r}$

but I'm having no progress with these to solve (b),

any help please

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$\frac{d}{dt} (\dot r -a\times r)= \ddot r -a\times \dot r=0$$
the  expression $\dot r -a\times r$ is constant in time. Denote it by $b$; done.

In part (c), the additional assumption delivers $b\perp a$, which makes it possible to write $b$ as the cross-product of $a$ with another vector.

In part (d), you differentiate the quantity which you want to prove constant, and use the ODE: 
$$\frac{d}{dt}((r+c)\cdot (r+c)) = 2 \dot r \cdot (r+c) =0$$
because $\vec r$ is the cross product of something with $r+c$.

And so on...